# How to create selector drawable from color code programmatically in android

Tags: android, selector-drawable

I want to create a selector drawable with `#000000` for selected and `#FFFFFF` for unselected state.

How can I create a drawable programmatically?

Currently I am doing it as following:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
ColorDrawable cdPress = new ColorDrawable(0xFF0000);
ColorDrawable cdUnPress = new ColorDrawable(0x0101DF);

states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected}, cdPress);
states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_selected}, cdUnPress);

view.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
view.setSelected(isSelected);
```

Comment: First you need to create `Drawable` from your color and then create `StateListDrawable` and set this `Drawable` with it's `State`. and then at last set this `StateListDrawable` as `BackgroundDrawable` to your `View`.

Comment: I know this But I have facing problem in this

Comment: StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
 ColorDrawable cdPress = new ColorDrawable(0xFF0000);
 ColorDrawable cdUnPress = new ColorDrawable(0x0101DF);

 states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected },cdPress);
 states.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_selected },cdUnPress);
 view.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
 view.setSelected(isSelected);

Comment: StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
ColorDrawable cdPress = new ColorDrawable(0xFF0000);
ColorDrawable cdUnPress = new ColorDrawable(0x0101DF);

states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected },cdPress);
states.addState(new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_selected },cdUnPress);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
view.setSelected(isSelected);

Comment: @UA post your all code in your question then ill solve your issue.....

Answer (score 1):

create stateListDrawable and pass to the view

```
   StateListDrawable stateListDrawable=new StateListDrawable();
   stateListDrawable.addState(new  int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}getColorDrawable(Colorcode));
   stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},getColorDrawable(Colorcode));
    ...
    mView.setBackground(stateListDrawable);
    ...
    }
    private static Drawable getColorDrawable(int colorCode) {
            return new ColorDrawable(colorCode);
    }
```

Comment: states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected }, getResources().getDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF0000)));

Comment: The method getDrawable(int) in the type Resources is not applicable for the arguments (ColorDrawable)

Comment: The method getDrawable(int) in the type Resources is not applicable for the arguments (ColorDrawable)

Comment: sorry i have modified..check it

Comment: states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, getColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));

But not in the case 
stateListDrawable.addState(new  int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}getColorDrawable(0xFFFFFF));